# How to solve: Error MT2002: Can not resolve reference: System.Void MonoTouch.Foundation.NSTimer::.ctor() (MT2002)

Tags: xamarin.ios, teechart

When using Steema TeeChart for MonoTouch (5.4.0) and compile to run on a physical device, I get Error MT2002: Can not resolve reference: System.Void MonoTouch.Foundation.NSTimer::.ctor() (MT2002).

I already know the answer but put the question here as a reference for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Steema TeeChart uses a bad version of NSTimer, that Xamarin removed in the latest version of MonoTouch.

There is a discussion about the issue here:
http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/error-MT2002-Can-not-resolve-reference-when-building-for-iPhone-td4656884.html

And a hotfix for it here:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6987

From MonoTouch 5.4.1, the hotfix will be built in and hotfix installing won't be necessary.